# ¿Porque me da problema al poner display:block a un botón?

Tags: html, css

el problema es que al poner display:block; al boton1 se aumenta su ancho no se porque ocurre eso le quiero agregar display block porque no puedo ponerle margin-top al botón porque no ocurre nada al ponerlo tengo que estar poniéndole una clase al texto para ponerle un margin bottom para así darle ese espacio que tiene y no quiero que este asi ayuda por favor(el Botón se ubica en el comentario galería se llama boton1)

este es mi codigo de css:

https://mega.nz/#!x3RlgSBQ!U-TAqmJgrEbAlVb8pZJBd30nERKFQotVLG4_bYrrbes

este es mi codigo de html:

https://mega.nz/#!Yr5ynASA!IYMVuXkrJlCXaNL8RNz7doCY2saSpdCL3_2HMiNnORY

les dejo el enlace mega porque no me pone bien lo que es html y css

```css
body {
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/*GALERIA*/
.textodegaleria{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.galeria{
 position:relative;
 width: 1366px;  
 background-color: transparent;
}
.boton1{
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fb4043;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #fb4043;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.boton1:hover{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #fb4043

}
.textoyboton{
 width: 572px;
  top: 160px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.imagen1{
 width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 8px;
}

.titulo-de-div{
 font-size: 36px;
  color: #46a5e5;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeria">
  <img class="imagen1" src="imagenes/div1.jpg">
  <div class="textoyboton">
  <h2 class="titulo-de-div">health and wellbeing</h2>
  <p class="textodegaleria">Liberal,cocollaborative consumptionfluctuation social analysis,<br>
  rural United Nations outcomesfoundation deep engagement. 
  </p>
  <a class="boton1" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Por qué no creas un snippet en esta página?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que es el comportamiento normal de `display: block;`, agrega al ancho un 100%. `Button` es de tipo inline, por lo que tu necesitas una solución intermedia, es decir, basta con: `display: inline-block`.

**pd:** Por cierto, no es recomendable poner enlaces externos y menos si no son de visualizacion online, lo mejor es que uses el comando **`control + M`** o subas tu demo a codepen.io/pen.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/*GALERIA*/
.textodegaleria{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.galeria{
 position:relative;
 width: 1366px;  
 background-color: transparent;
}
.boton1{
  display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fb4043;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #fb4043;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.boton1:hover{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #fb4043

}
.textoyboton{
 width: 572px;
  top: 160px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.imagen1{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 8px;
}

.titulo-de-div{
 font-size: 36px;
  color: #46a5e5;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeria">
  <img class="imagen1" src="imagenes/div1.jpg">
  <div class="textoyboton">
  <h2 class="titulo-de-div">health and wellbeing</h2>
  <p class="textodegaleria">Liberal,cocollaborative consumptionfluctuation social analysis,<br>
  rural United Nations outcomesfoundation deep engagement. 
  </p>
  <a class="boton1" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar esto:

```
.boton1{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear:left;
}
```

o también:

```
.boton1{width: max-content;}
```

para otros casos:

```
.boton1{display: inline-block;}
```

también puede servirte:

```
.boton1{display: table;}
```